# Case-Control study with 1:N matching and a continuous outcome variable

Tags: small-sample, case-control-study

I'm interested to compare cases with controls on a continuous outcome variable. The cases are people with a certain disease, while the controls are matched on various criteria (age, sex, etc) thought to be relevant to the continuous outcome variable.

The number of controls per case I'll have isn't yet clear but will likely be 4. So it's a 1:N matching study in which N is probably 4.

If $N = 1$ (i.e. I have 1:1 matching of cases with controls), would it be legitimate to use a paired t-test to compare cases with controls? If not, what should I do?

If $N > 1$, let's say $N = 4$ (i.e. there are 4 controls for each case), what analysis would be appropriate to compare with cases with the controls.

Most likely I will have only 3 cases, each of whom would be matched with N=4 controls (so 12 controls in total). Such a small sample size, and the difficulty of obtaining more cases, makes me think that I might be best off just reporting descriptive statistics, but I am being encouraged to find a way to report inferential statistics if doing so is reasonable.

How should I proceed if I have only 3 cases, each matched with 4 controls? Would the best way to proceed change if the number of cases was larger?